# Not able to build project getting The command "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt install --target=dev" exited with code 1

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, npm-install

I have already install Node, and did the following steps.

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
Npm install
Grunt serve
```

Comment: can you uninstall `grunt` globally then re install and let know whether the error is still there?

Comment: Yup still same error i uninstall it and again installed .